# Linq skip first where (linq to objects)

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-objects

I have the need to skip the first element that matches a predicate as a linq query. So far as I can tell the best I can do is something like this:

```
var list = new [] {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
var skippedFirstOdd = false;
var skipFirstEvenNumber = list.SkipWhile(number => 
                                         {
                                             if(number % 2 != 0)
                                             {
                                                 skippedFirst = true;
                                                 return true;
                                             }
                                             else
                                             {
                                                 return false;
                                             }
                                         });
```

Which works (I think), but isn't very elegant. Is there a cleaner way to achieve this?

Comment: Do you want to skip the first element or do you want to skip all the elements up to the first even number? And why to you set the `skippedFirst` variable? Do you need that?

Comment: What I'm trying to do is to return all elements, except the first one that matches the predicate.

Comment: Can you explain why the "Skip" extension method does not do what you want?  Why not just do sequence.Where(whatever).Skip(1) ?

Comment: Maybe it's my miss-understanding of skip. I want to get all the elements in a series, except for the first one matching the predicate. For example if the list was {2,2,1,3,5} I might want all except the first odd number, so I'd get back {2,2,3,5}

Comment: Got it. You don't want "all the elements in the sequence that match the predicate, except the first one". You wall "all the elements in the sequence, except the first one that matches the predicate." (Which is what you said -- but it's a potentially tricky distinction to understand.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could write an iterator-block extension method:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> SkipFirstMatching<T>
      (this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, bool> predicate)
{        
    if (source == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("source");

    if (predicate == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("predicate");

    return SkipFirstMatchingCore(source, predicate);
}

private static IEnumerable<T> SkipFirstMatchingCore<T>
      (IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, bool> predicate)
{            
    bool itemToSkipSeen = false;

    foreach (T item in source)
    {
        if (!itemToSkipSeen && predicate(item))
            itemToSkipSeen = true;

        else yield return item;
    }
}
```

And use it as:

```
var list = new [] { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 };
var skipFirstEvenNumber = list.SkipFirstMatching(i => i % 2 == 0);
```

---

By the way, your current code doesn't seem correct at all. The variable is called `skipFirstEvenNumber`, but the query is skipping *odd* numbers. Secondly, you appear to try to be using a side-effect to get the query to work, but you are only *setting* the flag variable, not reading it. Consequently, your current code should work just like a normal `SkipWhile`.

**EDIT**: Made argument-validation eager.

Comment: Why was there a "need" to split the solution in two distinct methods?

Comment: @LucMorin: So that argument-validation can be eager but the query itself can run deferred.

Comment: is that a known pattern with guidance, or is that like an informal thing a lot of people do? If you have some paper on the subject to share, they will be devoured ;-)

Comment: See: ]https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/09/03/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-2-quot-where-quot/] In particular, "We’ve just hit a design flaw in C#. Iterator blocks in C# simply don’t work nicely when you want to split execution between "immediate" (usually for validation) and "deferred". Instead, we have to split our implementation into two: a normal method for validation, which then calls the iterator method for the deferred processing"